# Why can I not use the indexOf function in my angular 2 typescript code?

Tags: javascript, angular

I get the error:

EXCEPTION: value.indexOf is not a function

whenever I try to use a javascript function. Here is the code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'id'
})
export class IdPipe {
    transform(value: string): string {
        let start = value.indexOf('"id": "')
        let id = value.substring(start + 7, start + 7 + 36);

        return id;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to make this work? I see similar examples in other people's code, so I think this should work.

Comment: Can you check the type at the start of the function? `console.log(typeof value);`

Comment: The error means that the value of `value` is something that does not have an `indexOf` property. You can `console.log(typeof value)` before that to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

you should insert condition in the begining of the transform function

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'id'
})
export class IdPipe {
    transform(value: string): string {
        if(value !== null && value !== undefined){
          let start = value.indexOf('"id": "')
          let id = value.substring(start + 7, start + 7 + 36);

          return id;
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe will be executed multiple times. Some of these times, like when your component hasn't fully initialized yet, "value" will be `null` or possibly `undefined`, and then it will not have the `indexOf` method. That's why you're getting this error.

Add a safety check:

```
transform(value: string): string {
    if (!value) return value;

    let start = value.indexOf('"id": "')
    let id = value.substring(start + 7, start + 7 + 36);

    return id;
}
```

(I generally find it preferable to return early, but Yoav Schniederman's answer is perfectly valid as well.)